# Issue with get_file_contents and scope in PHP

Tags: php, scope, file-get-contents

When I'm developing websites, I use a very (very) simple system of creating pages:

```
//$_page is, of course, declared above the loop, just as $needed_modules is.

foreach ($needed_modules as $part) 
{
    global $_page;

    if (file_exists($part)) {

        $_page . file_get_contents($part);
    } else {
        //404
    }
}

echo $_page;
```

Now, the problem is that file_get_contents doesn't return anything: not false, not a string, nada (and the file is ***not*** empty).

Execution *does* go inside the `if` and $part (which corresponds to a filename with relative path) isn't just set, but it *actually points to the file*.

Why is it that $_page is empty (as opposed to being *set*, isset($_page) actually evaluates to `TRUE`)?

**Edit:** Error-reporting is on full throttle on my server, and the logs show *nothing* out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the returned value. Try this:

```
$_page .= file_get_contents($part);
```

Comment: Ooh. Now I'm feeling ridiculously ashamed. Oh well. Thank you! o/

Comment: Och hey ho, märkte väl att du skrev på svenska (och är från kalmar med!) :)

Answer (score 5):

You are not saving the return value of `file_get_contents`:

```
$_page . file_get_contents($part);
```

I think you meant to say:

```
$_page .= file_get_contents($part);
```